# Require module throwing error in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a permissions structure for users in my application. I created a `permissions.rb` file in the `lib/` directory in my rails application.

When I try to `include Permissions` in my `user` model I am getting this error.

[image]

This is what I have in the `user` model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Permissions

  ...

end
```

How can I include this file and its methods without getting this error?

Comment: post your permissions module content. put the module in `model/concerns`

Comment: There is no code in my permissions module at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be good if you use autoload file when application start then it would like to on the `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Or you can use `user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'permissions.rb')
end
```

The module would look like this, always make sure the naming conventions is right like if run module name on the console with `underscore` then he would give your file name, see the below if your module name is `Permissions` then

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
2.3.4 :001 > "Permissions".underscore
 => "permissions"
```

your file name is `permissions.rb`

```
#=> permissions.rb
module Permissions
    ...
    def self.method #=> method name instead of the method
        #=> code staff here
    end
    or
    def method #=> method name instead of the method
        #=> code staff here
    end
    ...
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If I use that autoload path in `application.rb` will it then load all modules and directories in my `lib` folder?

Comment: Yes, see this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-availability

Answer (score 1):

To include modules under lib folder you will need to add your lib folder in autoload_path in your application.rb

`config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib/)`

add this line in your application.rb.